# Wrong Date format while converting : Python

Tags: python

I have mentioned a multilevel dictionary which contain various times with various events. This is code i want to subtract two events of save for calculate difference between them:

```
{'eventtime': 
    {'6': {'keypressevent': '14:08:33:806443', 'eventdestroytime': '14:08:35:144520', 'systemtime': '14:08:29:143176', 'keyreleaseevent': '14:08:38:574716'}, 
     '7': {'keypressevent': '14:08:02:318642', 'eventdestroytime': '14:08:02:025625', 'systemtime': '14:07:55:025225', 'keyreleaseevent': '14:08:05:590829'}, 
     '5': {'keypressevent': '14:08:22:198779', 'eventdestroytime': '14:08:21:855759', 'systemtime': '14:08:16:854473', 'keyreleaseevent': '14:08:27:143062'}, 
     '3': {'keypressevent': '14:08:10:919134', 'eventdestroytime': '14:08:10:592115', 'systemtime': '14:08:07:590944', 'keyreleaseevent': '14:08:14:854359'}
}, 
'userinfo': {'gender': 'm', 'usercode': 'TY123', 'weight': '65', 'age': '26', 'event': 'r', 'height': '165'}}
```

While i convert time using strptime in below for loop. I get wrong output of time format:

```
for ct in self.reproductioninfo['eventtime']:
    print(datetime.strptime(self.reproductioninfo['eventtime'][ct]['keypressevent'], '%H:%M:%S:%f'))
```

Output is : Wrong

```
1900-01-01 14:08:33.806443
1900-01-01 14:08:02.318642
1900-01-01 14:08:22.198779
1900-01-01 14:08:10.919134
```

Output should be :

```
14:08:33.806443
14:08:02.318642
14:08:22.198779
14:08:10.919134
```

and i want to subtract that time also but while subtract
Error is : **datetime.time() is not supported operand**

Comment: Why is this wrong? Your input has no day, month, any year. So it is only a time on `1900-01-01`.

Comment: Yes, i don't know why this is happening. In my previous same code works fine.

Comment: this is python 3.4, parenthesis is required and look my code i have used same code with "()"

Comment: What do you mean by 'subtract that time'?

Comment: i want difference of two time events

Answer (score 0):

[`strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) returns a `datetime` instance *including year, month, and day*. If you don't provide these in your input, they will be `1900-01-01`.

Comparing two `datetime` instances works, printing them with `strftime`, too.

```
import datetime

format = "%H:%M:%S:%f"
d1 = "14:08:33:806443"
d2 = "14:08:02:318642"

p1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(d1, format)
p2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(d2, format)

print(p1 > p2)

print(p1.strftime(format))
print(p2.strftime(format))

print(p1 - p2)
```

Output:

```
True
14:08:33:806443
14:08:02:318642
0:00:31.487801
```

Comment: I have imported

    from datetime import datetime
    print(datetime.strptime(self.reproductioninfo['eventtime']['7']['keypressevent'], '%H:%M:%S:%f'))

Comment: I don't understand your comment.

Comment: Output is :

   1900-01-01 14:08:33.806443

Comment: Yes, because you have a `datetime`. If you `print` it, the year, month, and date will be printed, too. If you want to print only hour, minute, etc., use `strftime`.

Comment: I got this error:  

print(datetime.strftime(self.reproductioninfo['eventtime'][ct]['keypressevent'], '%H:%M:%S:%f'))
TypeError: descriptor 'strftime' requires a 'datetime.date' object but received a 'str'

Comment: I am not getting same out see my out is like this  

  -1 day, 23:59:59.538974